# code check for multiple of 3 and 5

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code with javascript for this problem :

"If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

but the result is false and i don't know why? can you help me guys

my code is :

```
function multipleSum(n){   
   var sum = 0;
   for(var i = 1; i<n; i++){
     var m3 = 3 * i;
     var m5 = 5 * i;    
     if(m3 < n  ){
       sum=sum+m3
     }
     if(m5 < n ){
       sum=sum+m5;
     }
     //if(m3 > n && m5 > n) {console.log(m3,m5,sum);break;}
   }
   return sum
}
console.log(multipleSum(1000)) //266333 but correct one is 233168 why?
```

Comment: Hint: Why are you multiplying each number by 3 and 5?

Comment: @charlietfl that's actually a very good approach now when I think about it. I just made changes in my answer to fit his solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. You should be iterating on each number (specified in range), and see if the *modulus* of the number with 3 or 5 is 0 or not. If modulus is zero, it means the number is divisible.

```js
function multipleSum(n){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i<n; i++){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 ==0){ // gives reminder of 0, divisible by either 3 or 5
      sum += i; // add in sum if that's the case.
    }
  }
  return sum
}
console.log(multipleSum(1000))
```

**Edit**: tried some time understanding why you went with multiply approach, I think you are gathering factors and want to break out early from the loop instead of iterating on entire collection. This should help you:

```js
function multipleSum(n){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i<n; i++){
    var m3 = i * 3;
    var m5 = i * 5;
    if(m3 > n) break; // breaks early!!
    if(m3 < n) sum += m3
    if(m5 < n && m5 % 3 != 0) sum += m5; // make sure number is not divisible by 3, say m5 = 15, it will be captured as multiple of 3 anyway, we don't want duplicates.
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(multipleSum(1000))
```

Comment: This is nice way! `:D`

Comment: Hey, is this the way I did too. I am kinda confused with your second approach... `:(` But yeah, gives the same result.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i just edited to make some inline comments in code. It's actually pretty good. Instead of checking if each number is divisible or not, I am getting factors of 3 and 5, and as long as factor is less than n, i'm adding that in sum. EXCEPT, multiple of 5 which can be divisible by 3.

Comment: @PraveenKumar because say inside the loop, say n = 3, m3 = 9, m5 = 15.. I will skip addition of 15, because at n = 5, m3 = 15(this will be captured), m5 = 25.

Comment: Ha!!! I got it... So it's like my solution, except you are also not checking for those that are divisible by 3 and 5 in the 5 loop. Gotcha... Superb!!!

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar :). And I'm not saving the factors in any intermediate array.

Comment: Yes, coz I am doing it at the end, I am saving it... `:D`

Comment: thx alot i don't know that multiple could repeat like number 15 multiple for 3 and 5 and that make my result wrong

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is flawed in the way that, all the multiplications of `3 * 5` is doubled. Remember, you have:

```
3 * 1
5 * 1
3 * 2
3 * 3
5 * 2
3 * 4
3 * 5
5 * 3   // Here comes the dupe.
```

I would do this in a different way.

1. Get all the multiples of 3 in an array.
2. Get all the multiples of 5 in an array.
3. Break the loop when both the multiplications are greater than `n`.
4. Merge both the arrays.
5. Remove the duplicates.
6. Add everything using the `.reduce()` function.

```js
var num = 1000;
var m3 = [];
var m5 = [];

for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  if (i * 3 < num)
    m3.push(i * 3);
  if (i * 5 < num)
    m5.push(i * 5);
  if (i * 3 > num)
    break;
}

m35 = m3.concat(m5);

m35u = m35.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return m35.indexOf(item) == pos;
});

console.log(m35u.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
```

I get `233168` as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one liner (your home work: explain how this works ;):

```js
console.log( 
  Array.from({length: 1000})
    .reduce( (p, n, i) => p + (i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0 ? i : 0), 0 )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe answer you.Thank

```
const solution = (numb) => {
    const collectedNumb = [];
    const maxDividing = parseInt(numb / 3);
  
    for (let idx = 1; idx <= maxDividing; idx++) {
      const multipled3 = idx * 3;
      const multipled5 = idx * 5;
  
      multipled3 < numb && collectedNumb.push(multipled3);
      multipled5 < numb && collectedNumb.push(multipled5);
    }
    const uniqCollected = [...new Set(collectedNumb)].sort((a, b)=> a-b);
  
    console.log(uniqCollected);
  
    const reduced = uniqCollected.reduce((acc, numb) => acc + numb, 0);
    return reduced;
  };
```